# No pasa al visor de pdf usando React to print

Tags: reactjs, pdf, print

Quiero pasar el contenido de un formulario a pdf. Pero, el problema es que no lo muestra, en seguida muestro el código del mismo:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"; 
import { useReactToPrint } from "react-to-print";

const Verhistorialmedicogeneral = () => {   
    const { id } = useParams(); 
    const compoentPDF= useRef();
 

      const VerHistorialPDF=useReactToPrint({
             content: ()=>compoentPDF.current,
             documentTitle:"Historial Médico de Medicina General",
             onAfterPrint:()=>alert("PDF Guardado")
      }); 

      


        return ( 
          <React.Fragment>
             <div className="card">
             <div ref={compoentPDF}>   
                <div className="card-header">
                    Historial Médico de Medicina General
                </div>
                
                <div className="card-body">
                    <form   id="webFrmHistorialMedicinaGeneralReporte"> 
                             
                                
                    

                               <h4>Antecedentes Personales NO Patológicos</h4>
           

           <div className="form-group">
                                 <div> 
                                     <label htmlFor="">ID del Expediente:</label>
                                     <input type="text"  value={Idexpedientepaciente || ''}  name="txtidexpediente" id="txtidexpediente" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={6}  placeholder="" required readOnly></input>
                                </div>
                       
                                <div className="form-group">
                                     <label htmlFor="">ID del Paciente:</label>
                                     <input type="text"  value={id || ''}  name="txtidpaciente" id="txtidpaciente" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={6}  placeholder="Teclea nombre del personal" required readOnly></input>
                                </div>
                                    
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="">Domicilio:</label>
                                    <input type="text" onChange={e=>Dironochange(e.target.value)} value={txtDir || ''}  name="txtDir" id="txtDir" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={80}  placeholder="Teclea ocupación" readOnly ></input>
                               </div>

                                <div className="form-group">
                                     <label htmlFor="">Nombre Completo:</label>
                                     <input type="text" onChange={e=>nombrepacientechange(e.target.value)} value={txtnombpaciente || ''}  name="txtnombpaciente" id="txtnombpaciente" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea nombre del personal" readOnly ></input>
                                </div>

                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="">Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>
                                    <input type="date" onChange={e=>fechanaconochange(e.target.value)} value={txtFechaNac || ''} name="txtFechaNac" id="txtFechaNac" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={15}  placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"   min="1930-01-01" max="2080-12-31" readOnly></input>
                                </div>

                              

                                 
                               <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="">Celular:</label>
                                    <input type="text" onChange={e=>celularonochange(e.target.value)} value={txtCelular || ''} name="txtCelular" id="txtCelular" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea nota de la ocupación" readOnly></input>
                               </div>


                               <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="">Género:</label>
                                        <input type="text" onChange={e=>nomgenonochange(e.target.value)} value={txtnomgen || ''}  name="txtnomgen" id="txtnomtipofam" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={15}  placeholder="Teclea nombre del personal" readOnly ></input>
                               </div>  
                               <br></br><br></br>
           
                         <div className="form-group">
                              <label htmlFor="">Lugar de nacimiento:</label>
                              <input type="text" onChange={e=>lugarnacimientopacientechange(e.target.value)} value={txtlugardenacimientopaciente || ''}  name="txtlugardenacimientopaciente" id="txtlugardenacimientopaciente" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={15}  placeholder="Teclea lugar de nacimiento del paciente" readOnly ></input>
                         </div>   

                         <div className="form-group">
                              <label htmlFor="">Lugar de residencia:</label>
                              <input type="text" onChange={e=>lugarrecidenciapacientechange(e.target.value)} value={txtlugarderecidenciapaciente || ''}  name="txtlugarderecidenciapaciente" id="txtlugarderecidenciapaciente" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={15}  placeholder="Teclea lugar de recidencia del paciente" readOnly ></input>
                         </div>   
                         <div className="form-group">
                              <label htmlFor="">Hábito tabáquico:</label>
                              <input type="text" onChange={e=>habitotabaquicopacientechange(e.target.value)} value={txthabitotabaquico || ''}  name="txthabitotabaquico" id="txthabitotabaquico" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={15}  placeholder="Hábito tabáquico"  readOnly></input>
                         </div>   
                         <div className="form-group">
                              <label htmlFor="">Hábito alcóholico:</label>
                              <input type="text" onChange={e=>habitoalcoholicopacientechange(e.target.value)} value={txthabitoalcoholico || ''}  name="txthabitoalcoholico" id="txthabitoalcoholico" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={15}  placeholder="Hábito alcóholico" readOnly ></input>
                         </div>   
                         <div className="form-group">
                              <label htmlFor="">Ocupación actual:</label>
                              <input type="text" onChange={e=>ocupacionactualpacientechange(e.target.value)} value={txtocupacionactualpaciente || ''}  name="txtocupacionactualpaciente" id="txtocupacionactualpaciente" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={15}  placeholder="Teclea ocupación actual del paciente" readOnly ></input>
                         </div>   
                         <div className="form-group">
                              <label htmlFor="">Adicciones:</label>
                              <input type="text" onChange={e=>adiccionespacientechange(e.target.value)} value={txtadiccionespaciente || ''}  name="txtadiccionespaciente" id="txtadiccionespaciente" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={15}  placeholder="Adicciones del paciente" readOnly ></input>
                         </div>   
                         <div className="form-group">
                              <label htmlFor="">Alergias:</label>
                              <input type="text" onChange={e=>alergiaspacientechange(e.target.value)} value={txtalergiaspaciente || ''}  name="txtalergiaspaciente" id="txtalergiaspaciente" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={15}  placeholder="Alergias paciente" readOnly ></input>
                         </div>   
                         <div className="form-group">
                              <label htmlFor="">Tipo de sangre:</label>
                              <input type="text" onChange={e=>tipodesangrepacientechange(e.target.value)} value={txttipodesangrepaciente || ''}  name="txttipodesangrepaciente" id="txttipodesangrepaciente" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={15}  placeholder="Teclea tipo de sangre" readOnly ></input>
                         </div>   
              </div>   
                                
              <br></br><br></br>    
                     
       <table className="table" >
            <thead>
                 <h4>Antecedentes Hereditarios y Familiares</h4>
                <tr>
                    <th>Padecimiento</th>
                    <th>Familiar que lo padece</th> 
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {antecedenteshereditariosyfamiliares.map(
                       (antecedenteshereditariosyfamiliares)=>(
                         <tr key={antecedenteshereditariosyfamiliares.Id_Tipo_familiar}> 
                            <td>{antecedenteshereditariosyfamiliares.Padecimiento_hereditario_familiar}</td>
                            <td>{antecedenteshereditariosyfamiliares.Nom_tipo_familiar}</td> 
                         <td>
                             
                          </td>  
                         </tr>
                        )   
                    )
                }                             
               </tbody>
               <br></br><br></br> 

               <thead>
                 <h4>Listado de Antecedentes Personales Patológicos</h4>
                <tr>
                    <th>Enfermedad</th>
                    <th>Fecha de inicio</th> 
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {antecedentespersonalespat.map(
                       (antecedentespersonalespat)=>(
                         <tr key={antecedentespersonalespat.Id_enfermedad}>
                            <td>{antecedentespersonalespat.Nombre_enf}</td>
                            <td>{antecedentespersonalespat.Fecha_inicio_enfermedad}</td>  
                          <td>
                          
                          </td>
                         </tr>
                        )   
                    )
                }                             
               </tbody>
               <br></br><br></br> 
             
           
               


           </table> 
                         <div className="input-group">
                                    <span className="input-group-btn">       
                                    
                                        <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={VerHistorialPDF} aria-label="">Pasar a PDF</button>
                                     
                                    </span>                                    
                          </div> 
                            

                    </form>  
                                            
                </div>   
                             
             </div>
             </div> 
          </React.Fragment>
         );
    }
 
export default Verhistorialmedicogeneral;
```

Aquí cabe aclarar que si muestra toda la información en pantalla (información que viene de la API). Pero, el problema es que no manda al visor pdf. Ya probé en otro formulario y si funciona (es decir, si manda al visor de pdf), no entiendo si es una limitante por el número de tablas o de información. De hecho, cuando le doy a convertir a pdf me pone mucha información en la URL. Francamente, no sé cual sea el problema. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?, o bien, ¿existe alguna otra forma más sencilla de hacer esto?. Gracias y saludos.